# RangeAnalysis and V3022

Tags: pvs-studio

Consider the code below:

```
for (var i = int.MaxValue - 2; i < int.MaxValue; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
Console.WriteLine();

for (var i = int.MaxValue - 2; i <= int.MaxValue - 1; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
Console.WriteLine();

for (var i = int.MaxValue - 2; i <= int.MaxValue; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

The two first loops are expected to print out only the third and second largest integer.
The last loop has a bug where `i` will overflow to `int.MinValue` and causing an infinite loop.

Running it gives the expected output.

```
2147483645
2147483646

2147483645
2147483646

2147483645
2147483646
...
```

PVS Studio raises three warnings:

> V3022 Expression 'i < int.MaxValue' is always true.
>
> V3022 Expression 'i <= int.MaxValue - 1' is always true.
>
> V3022 Expression 'i <= int.MaxValue' is always true.

The bug in the last loop is correctly reported, but the two first warnings are false positives.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. We will look at this false positive soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have fixed this false positive. The fix will be available with the next release.

Comment: Just to let you know, this still triggers for `uint i = 0; do { ++i; } while (i != uint.MaxValue);`